# sequelize bulkupdate error on column "0" of relation does not exist

Tags: node.js, orm, sequelize.js, bulkupdate

With the following migration script:

```
const rules = [
  { type: 'read', target: 'table1', service: 'admin', scope: 'self', field: 'id' },
  { type: 'read', target: 'table2', service: 'admin', scope: 'self', field: 'id' }
]

module.exports = {
  up: (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    rules.map(({ type, target, service }) => { console.log( type, target, service) })
    return queryInterface.bulkUpdate(
      'rules',
      rules,
      {[Sequelize.Op.or]: rules.map(({ type, target, service }) => { console.log( type, target, service); return {type, target, service} })},
    ).then(ids => {
      console.log(ids);
    })
  },
```

I am seeing the sql being executed:

```
Executing (default): UPDATE "rules" SET "0"=$1,"1"=$2 WHERE (("type" = $6 AND "target" = $7 AND "service" = $8) OR ("type" = $9 AND "target" = $10 AND "service" = $11) OR ("type" = $12 AND "target" = $13 AND "service" = $14) OR ("type" = $15 AND "target" = $16 AND "service" = $17) OR ("type" = $18 AND "target" = $19 AND "service" = $20))
```

Which gives this error:

```
ERROR: column "0" of relation "rules" does not exist
```

But how come it makes the index instead of the actual column name.

Comment: I'm having this same issue, did you find out the solution?